# Why code continues to run even after 'return res.send();'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I don't understand why code continues to run even after return and res.send() was called. This is a [GIST](https://gist.github.com/thalesfsp/80fb332ee671e67fa0b4) to help to understand.

UPDATE:

Well, after help of community now discovery and understand that the problem is that return `res.send();` occur async, in parallel of `console.log()`.

In this specific case, the solution is wrap inside `if/else`.

Thanks to @Tom and @PaulPro!

Comment: Does it still say `Hi!` if you change that to `Hi2!`? (Only to be 100% sure you do not have a stray `Hi!` anywhere else …)

Comment: Yes! I really don't understand why. It's not very important to me, but at some point impact my code. I really expected that nothing keep running after it

Comment: If *"Yes, it still say `Hi!`"* then you are probably not running the same file as you are editing – or you have that `Hi!` from somewhere else.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `Hi!` text is printed on the console if you use following code snippet (note there is no `return` next to `res.send`).

```
app.get('/asd', function (req, res) {
  res.send('OK');
  console.log('Hi!');
});
```

Following code snippet will not print `Hi!` on the console as the request handling function ends along with `res.send('OK');` expression

```
app.get('/asd', function (req, res) {
  return res.send('OK');
  console.log('Hi!');
});
```

The reason why you can see `Hi!` in the first instance is that the `res.send` function is performed asynchronously i.e. method sending response is queued in the JavaScript event loop and the request handling function continue execution and calls `console.log` with `Hi!` argument.

I hope that will help.

Comment: Sorry @Tom but it still print 'hi' even with return.

Comment: @CodeWarrior, in that case there must be another piece of code in your application (maybe somewhere with `app.use`) which also performs `console.log('Hi!')`. Can you please change `'/asd'` handler and modify `Hi!` to, say, `Hi! in /asd handler` to check if that changed text will be printed out.

Comment: look at this gist: https://gist.github.com/thalesfsp/80fb332ee671e67fa0b4 this is the code. I don't have app.use. :)

Comment: @CodeWarrior That Gist is completely different from what you posted in your question. You're not even returning from the same function that you log `Hi!` in. You're returning from an anonymous function. In fact the `console.log('Hi')` happens before the anonymous function is called.

Comment: @Paulpro no, console.log() is inside of app.get() scope. After the return res.send() its should not run.

Comment: @CodeWarrior, in the example, there are two functions executed before request handler: `middlewares.isAuthenticated` and `middlewares.validateReqBodyAgainst`. Also you are not using `return` along with `User.findOne` so surely it looks like the first code snippet. It would be case #2 if you used `return User.findOne ...`.

Comment: @CodeWarrior The `return` is from the anonymous function `function (err, doc) {`. You don't have any return's in the function `function (req, res) {`. If you add a return right before that console.log, it won't log.

Comment: @Paulpro, i will edit the GIST to better understand, wait

Comment: @CodeWarrior Maybe this will help you understand: http://jsfiddle.net/f7TV3/

Your GIST is similar to that. Sure you have a return somewhere in the code before `console.log`, but it's in a different function, and it gets executed after the `console.log` does.

Comment: @Paulpro my last try ;) i update the GIST.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after help of community now discovery and understand that the problem is that return res.send(); occur async, in parallel of console.log(). In this specific case, the solution is wrap inside if () {} else {}. Thanks to @Tom and @PaulPro!

Comment: I am very happy we could help.